# iFrame accessed with https is marked 'unencrypted' by Chrome ... why?

Tags: google-chrome, http, iframe, https

I am writing a basic web application that uses `<iframe>` elements for certain features.

The entire site uses `https`, including the links to and from the `iframe`, but when I view the website using Google Chrome and right-click on the displayed frame and look at "View Frame Info" --> Connection, I see the following message:

```
Your connection to www.example.com is not encrypted

The connection uses TLS 1.1.

The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.
```

Confusingly, it says that the connection is not encrypted ... and then it says that it IS encrypted.

I thought that whenever you use `https://`, the content is encrypted. Am I wrong? Or is Google Chrome referring to something else?

Comment: Anyone know why this might happen? I've recently noticed it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting this issue to the [Chromium bug discussion board](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-discuss/iframe/chromium-discuss/yV7rGTduDAo/C2RLCJgNUZYJ) and someone there indicated that it's a bug.